# RelativeSource FindAncestor without static resource in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

I'm new to WPF and the MVVM pattern so I have some problems with my bindings.

In a details view of a customer, I want to list some statuses in a combobox.

In my ViewModel the customer is at the root level, and so is the list of statuses.

When using a static resource, I can use:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=DataContext.PartGruppAll}"
```

on my ComboBox, but when I set the DataContext from code behind, it does not work, what am I doing wrong, in my opinion it should make no difference.

Best regards, 
Peter Larsson

Comment: Perhaps give us the viewmodel code as well. It might help

Answer (score 2):

In your binding, try setting AncestorType to your view class.  Something like

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type vw:MyView}}, Path=DataContext.PartGruppAll}"
```

where vw is your namespace where you keep you view and MyView is the name of your view class itself.

In my application I have declared vw like this

```
xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:MyApp.View"
```

(You probably didn't need that bit but I included just in case =)

Answer (score 0):

Its not because you might have a spelling mistake

```
Path=DataContext.PartGruppAll
```

might should be

```
Path=DataContext.PartGroupAll
```

Comment: No, sorry, there is a part of Swedish in that name, the correct name actually is PartGruppAll. :)

Comment: Ok, no worries... was just a hunch

Answer (score 0):

Oh one more thing...

If the StackPanel is up the same visual tree as the combo box then you dont need to find it in the binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding PartGruppAll}"
```

Should work as DataCoxtext's are searched up the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to give you some more details, the viewmodel is quite large so I'll try to shorten it.

I instantiate the viewmodel in my code behind for App.xaml

```
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        PartWindow pw = new PartWindow();


        var PartViewModel = new ViewModel.PartWindowViewModel();
        pw.DataContext = PartViewModel;

        pw.Show();
    }
```

Then in my page I bind the data to a stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=PartViewModel}">
```

I then display the Customer in a grid by binding to the Customer-property SelectedPart.

```
   <Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedPart}" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0">
```

My viewModel Looks like this:

ViewModelClass

- SelectedPart

Name and other properties

- StatusList

Name and other properties

Nothing really complicated I think... The grid is tied to the selected customer, that's the problem.